# How to group an SQL request yet do a random of it per id each time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am taking information from a table randomly. Each article has an author id `ojm_pages_articles.id_ojm_peoples_author`. Each author has several articles `ojm_pages_articles.id_article`.

I am trying to select a random article for each author but I don't want the same author to be selected twice. I did a `GROUP BY ojm_pages_articles.id_ojm_peoples_author` but it does not select random articles for each authors, instead it selects one article for each author and groups it.

This is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ojm_pages_articles.id_article, ojm_pages_articles.titre, ojm_pages_articles.description, ojm_pages_articles.id_rubrique,  ojm_pages_articles.id_ojm_peoples_author              

FROM  `ojm_pages_articles`              
WHERE ojm_pages_articles.this_is='article'  

GROUP BY ojm_pages_articles.id_ojm_peoples_author
        
ORDER BY rand(), 
ojm_pages_articles.classement_article ASC, 
ojm_pages_articles.id_article  DESC LIMIT 9
```

**How can I do a random request of articles but group it per authors in a way that any time the page is refreshed a random article for that author will be displayed? How to randomly group an SQL request per id each time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select only article and author, group by Author and the article id and see if that work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ojm_pages_articles.id_ojm_peoples_author, ojm_pages_articles.id_article
FROM  `ojm_pages_articles`              
WHERE ojm_pages_articles.this_is='article'  

GROUP BY ojm_pages_articles.id_ojm_peoples_author, ojm_pages_articles.id_article

ORDER BY rand(), 
ojm_pages_articles.classement_article ASC, 
ojm_pages_articles.id_article  DESC LIMIT 9
```

If it's working, you ca rejoin (this rowset) with the ojm_pages_articles again to retrieve the other fields.